# Sobre desempenho em tipagem de variável em funções e variáveis em typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Existe alguma diferença de desempenho em typescript ao utilizar a tipagem de variável em comparação com o any?

Exemplo:

```
minhaString: any;
minhaString: string;
```

Gostaria de saber também se existe diferença em tipar o retorno da função, exemplo:

```
minhaFuncao(){}

e minhaFuncao():void{}
```

Essa tipagem ajudaria no desempenho de alguma forma ou é mais pra seguir padrões de projeto?

Há algum estudo que mostre a diferença de desempenho quando uma função/variável é declarada como public, private, protected...?

Comment: Desempenho onde? Você sabe que o TypeScript é somente um *superset* do JavaScript e que no final tudo vira JS?

Comment: Obrigado, então não há diferença em tipar ou não as variáveis e retornos? Foi isso que eu perguntei. senti sua resposta meio grosseira

Comment: Estou começando agora

Comment: Não era a intenção, mas não confunda ser direto com ser grosseiro. Eu precisava entender se você ao menos tinha noção do que está trabalhando. Perguntar de desempenho sempre é muito delicado. Dificilmente quem pergunta especifica quais os parâmetros para se considerar ao comparar desempenho. Da forma que colocou pareceu que queria saber se a aplicação final muda com o tipo da variável e por isso pedi se você sabia o que era o TypeScript de fato.

Comment: Se está começando agora, recomendo que estude JS antes do TS.

Comment: Sobre ter diferença entre a tipagem veja no playground que o codigo gerado é o mesmo http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20teste%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Alet%20teste2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20testeClass%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20teste%3D1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20teste2%3D3%3B%0D%0A%7D O mesmo ocorre para os tipos de acesso.